# Crystal Syntax Propercase except acronymns

Tags: crystal-reports

I'd like to use the Crystal Syntax in a formula to populate data from a database into Propercase like:

```
propercase(string)
```

That would turn data in a column from
`LOREM IPSUM`
to
`Lorem Ipsum`

However, I don't want that to happen with acronyms. Let's say I have just one acronym used, that I'd like to keep in Uppercase. Is there anyway to add a case statement to the formatting so that the specified acronym doesn't change.

For example:
`LOREM IMPSUM(ABC)` should become `Lorem Ipsum(ABC)` **NOT** `Lorem Ipsum(Abc)`.

Would that type of formatting work in a Case Statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Replace`-function to change the acronyms back to uppercase after using the `Propercase`-function on the string:

```
Replace(Propercase("LOREM IMPSUM(ABC)"), "Abc", "ABC")
```

**Note:** If there's a word like `Abcdefg`, the result will be `ABCdefg`.